# Retrieving the three next times (in columns) occuring after now from a schedule table in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new at this so if you think this has been answered and could point me to the right article that would be great, I've looked, and I haven't found an answer, maybe it's just taken as given, who knows.

I'm trying to retrieve the next three times in a mysql table that occur after now for a given row.

e.g. a row looks something like this in the table.

IdNum , time1, time2, time3, time4, time5, time6, time7, etc.

if the current time is say 5:22 and it corresponds to a time after time3 but before time4, how can I query the table so that I get time4, time5 and time6, but not time7, time8 etc.

Thanks for taking the time to read my problem.

EDIT:

The table would be in the format as follows (where I have condensed it, there's going to be up to 100 columns, and probably as many rows)

---

```
| IdNum | Time1 | Time2 | Time3 | Time4 | Time5 | Time6 |  
---------------------------------------------------------
|   1   | 3:22  | 4:10  | 5:10  | 6:25  | 7:23  | 8:24  |
---------------------------------------------------------
|   2   | 4:32  | 6:17  | 6:55  | 7:25  | 8:45  | 10:21 |
```

and so on, and then I would want to provide the query with IdNum = 2, and time = 5:22 and have it return row[0] = 6:17, row[1] = 6:55, row [2] = 7:25.

Comment: It would surely help get you more **proper** answers if you posted the table schema ... the answer I provided you below took some assumptions ...

Comment: rather you post your schema or even some sample code which relates your question. your problem is hard to fix by us

Comment: @JEGM: If you are going to have (as you say) 100 columns, then your table needs normalization. First. Before you start writing complex (and slow and not maintainable) queries. **Normalize** the table: **http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization**

Comment: Your table violates 1st Normal Form. See the "Repeating groups across columns" section at the 1NF (1st Normal Form) article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't follow what you mean by normalize the table, it's already in what is a very basic form,

Comment: The idea is that it's a train schedule, where the IdNum represents the stop number, and the times are the times which a train stops at that location.  It's not necessarily important the order from left to right, just that the query retreives the three times closest to, but following the current time.  If this still violates these normalization principles, could you suggest a way of restructuring it so that it does not?

Answer (score 2):

In my poorest ad-hoc, freehand, untested mysql query:

```
 select * from table where times > 5:22 LIMIT 3
```

- Some information you should read about with respects to MySQL:

  - [LIMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/limit-optimization.html)
  - [Comparison Functions & Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html)

*note* this was posted before the sample schema was posted.

Comment: where does 'times' come from?  I'm basically trying to get the table to find an intersection of a row and a column, and then getting the next three entries in that row returned.

Comment: post your schema .. each time is in it's own column?  how many columns?